# Tone analyser only returns analysis for 1 sentence

Tags: ibm-watson, watson

When using tone analyser, I am only able to retrieve 1 result. For example, if I use the following input text.

`string m_StringToAnalyse = "The World Rocks ! I Love Everything !! Bananas are awesome! Old King Cole was a merry old soul!";`

The results only return the analysis for document level and sentence_id = 0, ie. "The World Rocks !". The analysis for the next 3 sentences are not returned.

Any idea what I am doing wrong or am I missing out anything? This is the case when running the provided sample code as well.

`string m_StringToAnalyse = "This service enables people to discover and understand, and revise the impact of tone in their content. It uses linguistic analysis to detect and interpret emotional, social, and language cues found in text.";`

Running Tone analysis using the sample code on the sample sentence provided above also return results for the document and the first sentence only.

I have tried with versions "2016-02-19" as well as "2017-03-15" with same results.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you want sentence by sentence analysis you need to send every separate sentence as a JSON object. It will then return analysis in an array where id=SENTENCE_NUM.

Here is an example of one I did using multiple YouTube comments (using Python):

```
def get_comments(video):
    #Get the comments from the Youtube API using requests

    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&maxResults=100&videoId='+ video +'&key=' + youtube_credentials['api_key']

    r = requests.get(url)
    comment_dict = list()

    # for item in comments, add an object to the list with the text of the comment

    for item in r.json()['items']:
        the_comment = {"text": item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal']}
        comment_dict.append(the_comment)

    # return the list as JSON to the sentiment_analysis function
    return json.dumps(comment_dict)

def sentiment_analysis(words):

    # Load Watson Credentials using Python SDK

    tone_analyzer = ToneAnalyzerV3(
    username=watson_credentials['username'], password=watson_credentials['password'], version='2016-02-11')

    # Get the tone, based on the JSON object that is passed to sentiment_analysis
    return_sentiment = json.dumps(tone_analyzer.tone(text=words), indent=2)
    return_sentiment = json.loads(return_sentiment)
```

Afterwards you can do whatever you want with the JSON object. I would also like to note for anyone else looking at this if you want to do an analysis of many objects, you can add sentences=False in the tone_analyzer.tone function.